# In WLAN network, does ARP always show the mac address of device's Wi-Fi interface?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, lan, mac-address, arp

Say, if some device is accessing the server in the local network, while being connected to it via WiFi, would an ARP command sent from that server always show the same mac-address, as the device broadcasts over WiFi?

In other words, would ARP sent from the local computer always match the mac-address being seen on Wireshark?

Comment: MAC addresses are only seen or relevant on the LAN where the host is connected. Frames, which contain MAC addresses, are stripped by routers, and the MAC addresses are lost as the packets are forwarded because the router will create new frames for the interface(s) to which if forwards the packets. Also, entries in an ARP table on a host will time out and need to be refreshed.

Comment: That's all clear. But will those MAC addresses stay the same or they can change during packet forwarding? I've just tried it in my home and corporate networks, and it showed the same address for `en0` on my Mac and `arp` sent from the other computer in the network. So I wonder if it's always like that?

Comment: As I explained, during packet forwarding, the frames are stripped off, and the original MAC addresses are lost. The only way to see the original source MAC address is to be on the same LAN as the sender.

Comment: Well, yes, the two devices are on the same network. One is just connected to it via WiFi, the other one is connected via Ethernet

Comment: Then the MAC addresses on the frames are the original MAC addresses.

Comment: @Ron Maupin... I believe he is asking what happens during layer-2 (same subnet) ARP requests. I.e before the layer-3 device strips on egress. There is probably confusion when he says wifi. As a home wifi router is technically three devices in one (switch, AP, and router). Where as his "corporate" network is probably using access points on their own vlans.

Comment: @Tim_Stewart, I understand. That's why I explained about the same and different LANs.

Comment: @Tim_Stewart, well, my home router is indeed three devices in one, but the corporate network has Cisco APs and the two computers were in different subnets, which is quite interesting.